# How to add a dynamic table in my pre-existing database after the main table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I made this database helper code to enable a table to enter items to a list table using the following code. The table for list included 3 attributes, item_id, item_name and item_cost.

```
//Database Information
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "budgetlist.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//Table Name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "List";
//Column Names
public static final String COL_ITEM_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
public static final String COL_ITEM_COST = "cost";
static final String[] columns = new String[]{DBhelper.COL_ITEM_ID,
        DBhelper.COL_ITEM_NAME,DBhelper.COL_ITEM_COST};


// creation SQLite statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + "(" + COL_ITEM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COL_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_ITEM_COST + " INTEGER )";
```

But now I have to store multiple lists in the database. So I made another database code using the same code modified version to enable a table of lists containing the attributes list_id, list_name, list_duration and list_budgetlimit, and I wanted to create the above lists dynamically with each list that is created in the table but I am unsure of how it works.
The code I'm currently working with and needs modification is below:

```
//List Table Name
public static final String TABLE_LIST_NAME = "ListDetails";
//List Column Names
public static final String COL_LIST_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_LIST_NAME = "item_name";
public static final String COL_LIST_DURATION = "dur";
public static final String COL_LIST_BLIMIT = "blimit";
static final String[] columns = new String[]{ListDBhelper.COL_LIST_ID,
        ListDBhelper.COL_LIST_NAME,ListDBhelper.COL_LIST_DURATION,ListDBhelper.COL_LIST_BLIMIT};
//Database Information
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "budgetlist.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// creation SQLite statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIST_NAME
        + "(" + COL_LIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COL_LIST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LIST_DURATION + " TEXT, " + COL_LIST_BLIMIT + " INTEGER )";

public ListDBhelper(Context context1, String databaseName, Context context, int databaseVersion) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("DB Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    System.out.println("Table Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIST_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
    System.out.println("DB Updated");
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what is problem here?

Comment: the problem here is i don't know to combine both tables in the same database with the second one dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database view. It's a searchable object in a database that is defined by a query.  Though a view doesn’t store data, some refer to a view as “virtual tables,” you can query a view like you can a table.  A view can combine data from two or more tables, using joins, and also just contain a subset of information.  This makes them convenient to abstract, or hide, complicated queries.
Version 2.1.0 and higher of the Room persistence library provides support for SQLite database views, allowing you to encapsulate a query into a class. Room refers to these query-backed classes as views, and they behave the same as simple data objects when used in a DAO.